# How do I eliminate TT's "Wide character in print" warning?

Tags: perl, unicode, template-toolkit

I have this warning every time I run my CGI-script (output is rendered by Template::Toolkit):

`Wide character in print at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/mach/Template.pm line 163.`

What's the right way to eliminate it?

I create the tt object using this config:

```
my %config = (
       ENCODING     => 'utf8',
       INCLUDE_PATH => $ENV{TEMPLATES_DIR},
       EVAL_PERL   => 1,
}
my $tt = Template->new(\%config);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this before the call to `$tt->process()` to have the output automatically encoded:

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
```

**Edit**: As [daxim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468533/how-do-i-eliminate-tts-wide-character-in-print-warning/2469635#2469635) mentioned, it's possible to utilize TT's encoding facilities:

```
$tt->process($infile, $vars, '-', { binmode => ':utf8' })
```

This relies on the widely used convention that the `'-'` filename gives you `STDIN` when it's opened for reading, and `STDOUT` when it's opened for writing.

**Edit 2**: BTW, the latter way doesn't seem to work for me under mod_perl (2.0.5).

Answer (score 1):

```
$tt->process($infile, $vars, $outfile, { binmode => ':encoding(UTF-8)' })
```

This is documented in http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template#process%28%24template%2C_%5C%25vars%2C_%24output%2C_%25options%29.